# is it possible to specify multiple images in an init container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, containers, kubernetes-pod

I currently uses several init container to pull images for different components. Init containers are running sequentially. Is it possible to pull all the images inside one init-container in parallel?

Comment: images are pulling via network. Usually network is a bottle neck. If your network throughput is 1 mb/s you need three seconds to copy three 1mb images. No matter parallelly or sequentially it happens. Anyway this question is not reproduceable and lack of details. Not sure if somebody able to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Each init container runs from an image. Include init container for each image that you need to do initialization before running the main container